Derivation of optical wave equation with polarization
I'm currently reading up on waveguide basics in "Nonlinear Fiber Optics" from G.P. Agrawal. There, I don't unterstand how one gets from

$$\nabla \times \nabla \times \mathbf{E} = - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{E}}{\partial t^2} - \mu_0 \frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{P}}{\partial t^2}$$

to the Fourier transformed equation

\begin{equation}
\nabla \times \nabla \times \mathbf{\tilde{E}}(\mathbf{r}, \boldsymbol{\omega}) - \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}(\boldsymbol{\omega})\frac{\boldsymbol{\omega}^2}{c^2} \mathbf{\tilde{E}}(\mathbf{r}, \boldsymbol{\omega}) = \boldsymbol{0}
\end{equation}

when assuming

\begin{equation} \mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r}, t) = \mathbf{P}_L(\mathbf{r}, t) + \mathbf{P}_{\text{NL}}(\mathbf{r}, t), \tag{2.1.8} \end{equation}
where the linear part $\mathbf{P}_L(\mathbf{r}, t)$ and the nonlinear part $\mathbf{P}_{\text{NL}}$ are related to the electric field by the general relations [2]-[4]
\begin{equation} 
\mathbf{P}_L(\mathbf{r}, t) = \varepsilon_0
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \boldsymbol{\chi}^{(1)} (t-t') \cdot
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}, t') \ \mathrm{d}t', \tag{2.1.9} 
\end{equation}

and $P_{\text{NL}} = 0$. Could someone write out the process? I'm especially confused about how to correctly apply the Fourier transformation here.

The linear polarisation is given as an impulse response integral, or a convolution between $\chi(t)$ and $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t)$ :
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{P}_L(\mathbf{r},t)=\epsilon_0\chi(t)\circledast\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t)
\end{equation}
where $\circledast$ is the symbol for convolution. I won't write the order above the susceptibility tensor to gain some time:)
Now first, the Fourier transform of $\partial_{tt}\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t)$ is $-\omega^2\tilde{\mathbf{E}}(\mathbf{r},\omega)$ by using the properties of the Fourier transform.
The Fourier transform of $\partial_{tt}\mathbf{P}_L(\mathbf{r},t)$ follows the same rule :
\begin{equation}
\partial_{tt}\mathbf{P}_L(\mathbf{r},t)=-\omega^2\tilde{\mathbf{P}}_L(\mathbf{r},\omega)
\end{equation}
The Fourier transform of a convolution of two functions is the product of their respective Fourier transforms :
\begin{equation}
\tilde{\mathbf{P}}_L(\mathbf{r},\omega)=\epsilon_0\tilde{\chi}(\omega)\tilde{\mathbf{E}}(\mathbf{r},t)
\end{equation}
Inserting all these results in your first equation gives you :
\begin{equation}
\nabla\times\nabla\times\tilde{\mathbf{E}}(\mathbf{r},\omega)=\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},\omega)+\mu_0\epsilon_0\omega^2\tilde{\chi}(\omega)\tilde{\mathbf{E}}(\mathbf{r},t)
\end{equation}
Now using $\mu_0\epsilon_0=1/c^2$ and $\epsilon(\omega)=1+\tilde{\chi}(\omega)$ gives you :
\begin{equation}
\nabla\times\nabla\times\tilde{\mathbf{E}}(\mathbf{r},\omega)-\epsilon(\omega)\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}\tilde{\mathbf{E}}(\mathbf{r},\omega)=0
\end{equation}
which is the desired equation.

Thanks a lot for your answer! About the double-time-derivate of the FT, why am I allowed to pull the derivative into the integral?

In fact, you take the TF of the double-time derivative of the polarization. I edited my post where it was written "the Fourier transform of $\mathbf{P}L(\mathbf{r},t)$. It is the Fourier transform of $\partial{tt} \mathbf{P}_L(\mathbf{r},t)$
